# how to use timeuuid names in cassandra

Tags: range, cassandra, uuid, slice

I have a problem, I would like to build logging system which will be using timeuuid type as a column name which will allow me ask for it later.

Since for range queries order by time I need to use timeuuid type I would like to ask you how can I specify range queries for timeuuid column names if timeuuid is every time unique and I don't realy know the column name because of that I just know the time when it has been stored ?

please help

Comment: I am confused by Cassandra Thrift API which requires me to provide columns name in slice query, but what if I don't know their names since they are uuid types ?

Comment: How do you even specify a timeuuid type in some Thrift binding?  I'm interested in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK all works, it turned out that column names are not required but you can't use null you need to use empty string instead